# How to setup OKTA device Authorization Flow on server in order to integrate OKTA SSO for Remote IOT devices

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

I need to authorize the IOT devices that do not have a UI but are able to call some APIs after being authorized by OKTA. I have the list of devices that needs to be authenticated for calling APIs. So I went through the [device code flow documentation](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/19/add-oauth-device-flow-to-any-server)

[OKTA Playground](https://www.oauth.com/playground/device-code.html) But I am not able to understand How come the POST https://authorization-server.com/device

client_id={CLIENT_ID} will work and how this endpoint be hosted on the okta authorization server.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okta currently doesn't have device flow implemented in GA, it's only in EA, I believe. So in case you want to follow it, here is the link - https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#device-authorize